# Can Spring Boot JSP limitation be solved?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Since I earn a living developing and supporting enterprise Java applications, I've long known of the Spring Boot `.jar` packaging limitation with JSP's.  But... I've never really seen it explained as to why.

Since this question is looking for someone with in-depth knowledge of the subject matter, I am going to forego a lot of trying to prove my research and how I got here but I did spend a couple of days on it over my holiday work break and have the following conclusion/question:

`Conclusion:`
From what I can tell, the limitation seems to stem from the fact that `JSP` rely on the `RequestDispatcher`.  In turn, the RequestDispatcher only has access to `resources` that are within the `servlet context`.

`Question:`
Couldn't the `RequestDispatcher` be 'upgraded' to handle a 'classpath:' like mechanism?  Because, isn't this the approach that frameworks like `Thymeleaf`, etc. use?

If the answer is 'no', then I'm guessing the reason would be 'security' related but I'm not really well versed at that level of J2EE architecture to understand the exact reason so am hoping somebody can tell me/us.

`Related Question:`
Since `.war` packaging can be executable, is there a downside to just using .war packaging?  I've searched high and low and can't find an answer to that.  As of now it seems to me that the answer is "who cares?"... just package as a .war.

> p.s.  This really is a serious question and I hope that others understand its motivation.  I'm not opposed to "new" technology (i.e. Thymeleaf templates in this case - and apologies for calling it "new" when these alternatives are quite proven) but it is my job to help companies navigate this landscape and, let's face it, there is a TON of time and money invested into J2EE with JSPs.  Refactoring and moving forward **is** possible but is also an investment of time which is, in turn, an investment of money which we all know to be limited.

> I am also aware of the trend towards front-end (React, etc.) vs. back-end (REST) architecures and do not disagree with it.  It is just not the focus of this post.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil Yes, there is a limitation.  You cannot use JSPs if you package your application as a .jar and this is a well established subject for Spring Boot.  I fully understand how to deploy a .war to a web container - this is not a noob question.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I will probably edit the question and add the link but it's inclusion would only be for the benefit of other's with questions.  I point this out because my question clearly states "Since this question is looking for someone with in-depth knowledge of the subject matter..."  I'm looking for someone with an in-depth knowledge of Spring Boot, J2EE Request Dispatcher, and the reason why it might not be subject to upgrade/modification.  I'm not looking for people who stumble upon this question and think they can answer it after doing a couple of google searches.